# GeoServer cascading WMTS failed tile removal

Tags: geoserver, wms, wmts, cascading

I'm wondering if there is a way to remove the failed tile message from a cascading WMTS, screenshot attached. These messages in the tiles appear between the available tiles and the bounding box.

[image]

Comment: A WMTS shouldn't have "missing" tiles - speak to your provider about that. Feel free to ask for an enhancement to the WMTS reader - we should probably have a debug flag to turn that display on/off

Comment: Thanks Ian, I have spun my wheels and learned more. Your advice to ask for an enhancement seems like the right thing to do. I tried testing uDig to see if the same behavior occurred but could not get it to work. Diving directly into GeoTools was a bit too much of a learning curve for me right now. Should this be a GeoTools or a GeoServer enhancement? Could you please provide a nudge in the right direction as to where/how to make that request?

Comment: Put it in GeoTools and I'll take a look when I next get a spare moment

Comment: Thank you! https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-7471